# The problem in deploy of flask application with OpenCV by Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, flask

I'm trying to deploy my flask application by Heroku but I have a problem.
In the app, the sent image will be analyzed by OpenCV but error happens.

According to the heroku log, the error is

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

In local environment, the apllication works.
I thought openCV is not installed in Heroku, so I added heroku.yml with below code.

```
build:
 languages:
  - python
 packages:
  - libopencv-dev
 run:
  web: gunicorn server:app --log-file -
```

However, the same error still happens...
Now, I doubt that import of opencv_contrib_python in Heroku is necessary but I don't know how to do.

I really need somebody's advise...
Thanks.

The actual code:

```
def load_model():
 global recognizer
 print(" * Loading pre-trained model ...")
 cascadePath = './haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'
 faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath)
 recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```